# Android - How to hide keyboard when search button of the keyboard is pressed?

Tags: android, keyboard

How to hide keyboard when search button of the keyboard is pressed?

When the user finishes inputing in edittext and press 'search button' fo the keyboard, the keyboard should be hidden..

Answer (score 7):

Set imeOptions to "actionSearch" in your xlm for edit text

Initialize listeners for your `EditText`

```
searchEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            performSearch();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Hide keyboard when user clicks search.

```
private void performSearch() {
    searchEditText.clearFocus();
    InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    ... perform search ...
}
```